# A tricky variant of SQL Intersect from three select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three select statements built based on parameters provided in three filter criteria on web site. All of them have a common PID column. At times these three select statements returns records, at time only two of them return and one will have 0 records and so on

The ask when all the queries are returning results, I want only those records which are intersect of all three, if two of them are returning results then resultant should be intersect of only those two which are returning and if only one is returning then result should be all records of query which are finding records. Joins fail when one of the select statements return 0 records and same problem with intersect.

Here is the actual code

```
SELECT 
    pdf.ID, ldf.ID  
FROM   
    dbo.UserDefinedField (nolock) u               
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.LDFUserDefinedField (nolock) AS ldf ON u.ID = ldf.UserDefinedFieldID      
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ParticipantUserDefinedField (nolock) AS pdf ON pdf.UserDefinedFieldID = u.ID         
                                                    AND (pdf.Value = ldf.Value OR ldf.Value = 'ALL') 
                                                    AND u.Name = 'CallType' AND ldf.ID = 69   

INTERSECT        

SELECT 
    pdf.ID, ldf.ID  
FROM   
    dbo.UserDefinedField (nolock) u               
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.LDFUserDefinedField (nolock) AS ldf ON u.ID = ldf.UserDefinedFieldID      
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ParticipantUserDefinedField (nolock) AS pdf ON pdf.UserDefinedFieldID = u.ID         
                                                    AND (pdf.Value = ldf.Value OR ldf.Value = 'ALL') 
                                                    AND u.Name = 'CenterName' AND ldf.ID = 69 

INTERSECT   

SELECT 
    pdf.ID, ldf.ID   
FROM   
    dbo.UserDefinedField (nolock) u               
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.LDFUserDefinedField (nolock) AS ldf ON u.ID = ldf.UserDefinedFieldID      
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ParticipantUserDefinedField (nolock) AS pdf ON pdf.UserDefinedFieldID = u.ID         
                                                    AND (pdf.Value = ldf.Value OR ldf.Value = 'ALL') 
                                                    AND u.Name = 'CenterID' AND ldf.ID = 69
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and show us the code you already tried

Comment: Your requirements are a bit unclear (showing sample data + expected results would be helpful), but it's possible you actually want a `union` instead of `intersect`. Also: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommend* to just use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: Thanks Marc for editing the code block. I was having tough time with it on my system.

Here is sample results
For ldf.id=69
First SQL query returns 1700 rows
Second SQL query returns 500 rows
Third SQL query returns 0 rows
I want the results which are common across all three (in this case common between first two as third is 0).  which in our case is 57

Since I am using intersect on all three SQL, it always returns 0. The above example works perfectly as long as all there queries return records. If any one of the query result is 0 the over all result goes to 0.
Hope this helps

Comment: assuming there is a table that has to have a record, make that table the first record in the list, then LEFT JOIN on the same criteria, except make sure the ID always comes from the table that has to have a record

Comment: Is the only difference between those three queries the `Name` value being searched for, and is the only paramaterized part the `69`? Also, for any *one* of those queries, would they only ever return *one* row for a particular `pdf.ID` and `ldf.ID` combination? If the answers are yes, this query looks like it could be vastly simplified.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yes Name value is the only one changing and yes 69 is the only paramaterized part. There will be multiple rows returned for a pdf ldf combination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the most efficient solution, but based on what you have, I would use a memory table to pull the full union, and then eliminate what you don't want.  Each separate query that returns results will remove unmatched results from the other two queries.

```
Declare @tblPDF TABLE (
    pdfId int not null, 
    ldfId int not null, 
    SourceName varchar(25) not null
    )

Insert into @tblPDF (pdfId, ldfId, SourceName)
SELECT 
    pdf.ID, ldf.ID, u.Name 
FROM   
    dbo.UserDefinedField (nolock) u               
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.LDFUserDefinedField (nolock) AS ldf ON u.ID = ldf.UserDefinedFieldID      
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ParticipantUserDefinedField (nolock) AS pdf ON pdf.UserDefinedFieldID = u.ID         
                                                    AND (pdf.Value = ldf.Value OR ldf.Value = 'ALL') 
                                                    AND u.Name = 'CallType' AND ldf.ID = 69   



Insert into @tblPDF (pdfId, ldfId, SourceName)
SELECT 
    pdf.ID, ldf.ID, u.Name 
FROM   
    dbo.UserDefinedField (nolock) u               
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.LDFUserDefinedField (nolock) AS ldf ON u.ID = ldf.UserDefinedFieldID      
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ParticipantUserDefinedField (nolock) AS pdf ON pdf.UserDefinedFieldID = u.ID         
                                                    AND (pdf.Value = ldf.Value OR ldf.Value = 'ALL') 
                                                    AND u.Name = 'CenterName' AND ldf.ID = 69 

Insert into @tblPDF (pdfId, ldfId, SourceName)
SELECT 
    pdf.ID, ldf.ID, u.Name 
FROM   
    dbo.UserDefinedField (nolock) u               
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.LDFUserDefinedField (nolock) AS ldf ON u.ID = ldf.UserDefinedFieldID      
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ParticipantUserDefinedField (nolock) AS pdf ON pdf.UserDefinedFieldID = u.ID        
                  AND (pdf.Value = ldf.Value OR ldf.Value = 'ALL') 
                                                    AND u.Name = 'CenterID' AND ldf.ID = 69         

IF exists(select 1 from @tblPDF where SourceName = 'Calltype')
  BEGIN
    Delete other
    From @tblPDF temp
    left outer join @tblPDF other on temp.pdfId = other.pdfId 
         and temp.ldfId = other.ldfid 
         and temp.SourceName <> other.SourceName
    Where temp.SourceName = 'CallType'
  END

IF exists(select 1 from @tblPDF where SourceName = 'CenterName')
  BEGIN
    Delete other
    From @tblPDF temp
    left outer join @tblPDF other on temp.pdfId = other.pdfId 
         and temp.ldfId = other.ldfid 
         and temp.SourceName <> other.SourceName
    Where temp.SourceName = 'CenterName'
  END

IF exists(select 1 from @tblPDF where SourceName = 'CenterID')
  BEGIN
    Delete other
    From @tblPDF temp
    left outer join @tblPDF other on temp.pdfId = other.pdfId 
         and temp.ldfId = other.ldfid 
         and temp.SourceName <> other.SourceName
    Where temp.SourceName = 'CenterID'
  END

select pdfId, ldfId from @tblPDF
```